# Convert Numeric value to Binary value in hive

Tags: hive

I want to get a numeric value immediately after a particular word in string In hive
example : APDSGDSCRAM051 in that I need to get numeric value after word RAM is it possible in hive after that I need to convert the resulted value  to binary

is it possible in hive ?

Note: its not a fixed length string

Answer (score 1):

```
'create table string_testing (c string);
insert into table string_testing values ('APDSGDSCRAM051');
select substr(c, instr(c, 'RAM') + 3) from string_testing;
OK
051`
```

Comment: You need to use substr and instr pre-defined hive functions